# Java: Selenium: WebDriver: Unable to Parse a List<WebElement> Object; Get Error "cannot be cast to java.lang.String"

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am new to java programming and I have a question on parsing a `List<WebElement>` object. I have a selenium webdriver script (written in java) that parses through a `List<WebElement>` object. Code Snippet of working code is below.

```
// Create a List composed of objects from the Client_Totals table
List<WebElement> tdlist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table[class='client_totals'] tr td"));        // 8-12-13 -- This Code Works -- KV

for(WebElement el: tdlist)
    {
    System.out.println(el.getText());
    }
```

This code works but I need to modify the script so that the script:

1. checks for the following values:

   - (a) 11 - 25 User Discount
   - (b) $17.55 (c) $4829.40
2. Outputs messages that inform user if the values were successfully located or not.

I began to write a new modified script (see below) using an iterator to loop through the tdlist but I am getting the following error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

```
// Create a List composed of objects from the Client_Totals table
List<WebElement> tdlist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table[class='client_totals'] tr td"));
Iterator itr = tdlist.iterator();                                                                         
while(itr.hasNext())
    {
    String value= (String)itr.next();
    System.out.println("Value : "+value);
    }
```

My Assessment: I think the error occurs because the tdlist is of a different type and, to work, the tdlist needs to be "cast" as a string array. However, I am not sure how to do this.

Next, I also need to add nested IF ELSE statements in the while structure. I've written pseudo code on what I think the appropriate code structure might look like:

```
While there are elements in the array
    {
    Parse through the array
    If value "11 - 25 User Discount" is found
        Print message "11 - 25 User Discount was found"
    Else If value "$17.55" is found
        Print message "$17.55 was found"
    Else If value "$4829.40" is found
        Print message "$4829.40 was found"
    Else
End While Loop
}
```

Comment: You should use typed `Iterator` (e.g. `Iterator<WebElement>`) to see such problem at compile time and not runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Ok.  Your problem is that tdList is a `List<WebElement>`, and `WebElement` cannot be cast to a String.

If you are using a compiler, you probably got a warning on the Iterator line, saying that it was generic.  You need to have that line be `Iterator<WebElement> iter = tdlist.iterator();`.  Then you can do `itr.next().getText()` and you don't have to cast anything!

Comment: The top code he said was working, but then he was getting an error in the second snippet of code.  I explained why.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my guess:

```
// Create a List composed of objects from the Client_Totals table
List<WebElement> tdlist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("selector text"));
for ( WebElement el: tdlist ) {
    System.out.println( el.getText() );
    Assert.assertTrue( el.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("a message"), 
        "There was no message."); 
    Assert.assertTrue( el.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("11 - 25 User Discount"), 
        "There was no 11 - 25 User Discount.");
    Assert.assertTrue( el.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("$17.55"), 
        "There was no $17.55.");
    Assert.assertTrue( el.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("$4829.40"), 
        "There was no $4829.40.");
}
```